# Wildfly LDAPS Integration Failed

Tags: jboss, ldap, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am experiencing authentication issue after converting LDAP to LDAPS. Here is an excerpt from my **standalone.xml** file. As you can see, I've added a trusted store with LDAPS certs. I am just wondering if I have missed something. I am on Wildfly v10.

```
<security-realms>            
        <security-realm name="LdapUserRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="identity.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxxx" alias="xxxxx"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <truststore path="cacerts" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="xxxxx"/>
                <ldap connection="LdapConnection" base-dn="dc=xxx,dc=ad,dc=xxx,dc=com" recursive="true">
                    <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName"/>
                </ldap>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <outbound-connections>
        <ldap name="LdapConnection" search-credential="xxxxxx​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​" search-dn="cn=-svc-xxx-xxx,OU=Svc,OU=XTX,OU=Admin,dc=xxx,dc=ad,dc=xxx,dc=com" url="ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx:636" />
    </outbound-connections>
```

Any pointer or suggestion are appreciated. It will be greatly appreciated if there is a working config file I can compare to. Can someone please share a JBoss/Wildfly config file (specifically **standalone.xml**) which connects successfully using LDAPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your LDAP outbound-connection to use the security-realm you created

```
<outbound-connections>
   <ldap name="ldap_connection" ... security-realm="LdapUserRealm"/>
</outbound-connections>
```